# Bootstrap @media query not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap in my project and trying to make the iframe resize when viewed on mobile. The problem is that it applies the property in @media (max-width:600px) to the desktop version of the site and it appears squashed. Width works just fine, but the height-auto property doesn't display well on desktop screens.

HTML:

```
  <iframe src="./bootstrap-remake_files/9m056zu9yr.html" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" class="wistia_embed" name="wistia_embed" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" mozallowfullscreen="mozallowfullscreen" webkitallowfullscreen="webkitallowfullscreen" oallowfullscreen="oallowfullscreen" msallowfullscreen="msallowfullscreen" style="width: 768px; height: 432px;" width="768" height="432" mytubeid="mytube1"></iframe>
```

CSS:

```
@media (max-width:600px){
   iframe{
     width:100%; 
     height:auto;
   }
}
```

In other words, I'd like my iframe to have

```
     width:100%; 
     height:auto;
```

only when on mobile.

Comment: The closing `}` is missing?

Comment: It's in the actual code. I missed it when pasting.

Answer (score 0):

Your `style="width: 100%; height: auto;"` overrides any style you will apply to your iframe through CSS, unless the properties are marked `!important`.

Comment: Inline style is not there anymore. Still doesn't work

Comment: Do you mean the rule inside the media query is still not applied, or the rule doesn't do what you want ? Because removing the inline style works fine for me.